# JS autocomplete with formatted entries in list

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am building an application in React, and I need an autocomplete / autosuggest widget. Can someone recommend on that will play well with React, and has the ability to put HTML formatted text in the list of suggestions (it is important that I can highlight letters in different colours). Preferably on that is simple to use.